# efficient way to remove a list of string from a big vector

Tags: c++, stl

I am using visual studio 2012 (windows) and I am trying to write an efficient c++ function to remove some words from a big vector of strings.

I am using stl algorithms. I am a c++ beginner so I am not sure that it is the best way to proceed. This is what I have did :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_set>
using std::vector;

vector<std::string> stripWords(vector<std::string>& input, 
                               std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string>& toRemove){ 
     input.erase(
         remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                     [&toRemove](std::string x) -> bool {
                         return toRemove.find(x) != toRemove.end();
                     }));
     return input;
}
```

But this don't work, It doesn't loop over all input vector.

This how I test my code:

```
vector<std::string>  in_tokens;
in_tokens.push_back("removeme");
in_tokens.push_back("keep");
in_tokens.push_back("removeme1");
in_tokens.push_back("removeme1");
std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string> words;
words.insert("removeme");
words.insert("removeme1");
stripWords(in_tokens,words);
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion on efficiency, if your `toRemove` set is large, you might want to pre-hash all strings (both in `input` and `toRemove`) and use the precomputed hashes to do the lookups.

Comment: by the way, since you are using c++11, unordered_set is included. you don't have to use the technical report (std::tr1).

Comment: Returning a copy of the vector seems inefficient since you're just returning the already modified input parameter, and you're not using the return value anyway.

Comment: You could speed up your lambda predicate a bit by taking the strings by `const&` instead of by value to avoid the extra copy: `[&toRemove](std::string x)` -> `[&toRemove](const std::string& x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach using `std::remove_if()` is nearly the correct approach but it erases just one element. You need to use the two argument version of `erase()`:

```
 input.erase(
     remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                 [&toRemove](std::string x) -> bool {
                     return toRemove.find(x) != toRemove.end();
                 }), input.end());
```

`std::remove_if()` reorders the elements such that the kept elements are in the front of the sequence. It returns an iterator `it` to the first position which is to be considered the new end of the sequence, i.e., you need to erase the range `[it, input.end())`.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by reasonable? is it O(nlog(n)) ?

Comment: @agstudy: no, I mean it makes sense to use `std::remove_if()`, just that you didn't use it correctly for your objective. It has time complexity _O(N * M)_ where _N_ is the number of elements in the sequence and _O(M)_ is the time complexity of calls to `toRemove.find(x)` which are expected to be constant. I have clarified the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need the two-argument form of `erase`. Don't outsmart yourself and write it on separate lines:

```
auto it = std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                         [&toRemove](std::string x) -> bool
                         { return toRemove.find(x) != toRemove.end(); });

input.erase(it, input.end());  // erases an entire range
```

Comment: thank you for the smart syntax:) any comment about efficiency?

Comment: @agstudy: it's one linear search for each element of the vector, plus the final erase.

Answer (score 1):

You've already gotten a couple of answers about how to this correctly.

Now, the question is whether you can make it substantially more efficient. The answer to that will depend on another question: do you care about the order of the strings in the vector?

If you can rearrange the strings in the vector without causing a problem, then you can make the removal substantially more efficient.

Instead of removing strings from the middle of the vector (which requires moving all the other strings over to fill in the hole) you can swap all the unwanted strings to the end of the vector, then remove them.

Especially if you're only removing a few strings from near the beginning of a large vector, this can improve efficiency a *lot*. Just for example, let's assume a string you want to remove is followed by 1000 other strings. With this, you end up swapping only two strings, then erasing the last one (which is fast). With your current method, you end up moving 1000 strings just to remove one.

Better still, even with fairly old compilers, you can expect swapping strings to be quite fast as a rule--typically faster than moving them would be (unless your compiler is new enough to support move assignment).

Comment: +1! interesting! I don't matter about the order. How do you write the swapping using stl?